# Cannot install composer on FreeBSD 10

Tags: freebsd, php

I have a FAMP SERVER I'm setting up.

1. FreeBSD 10.1
2. Apache 2.4
3. MySQL 5.6
4. Php 5.6

Everything working ok so far. I installed symfony no problem but now trying to install composer.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

I get the following output (see below) but I don't know how to correct the problem.

Tried review of Php.ini and the make file on mod_php56 in usr/ports.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The json extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-json

The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

The filter extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-filter

The hash extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-hash

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl code here

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured It out

I needed to run pkg install php56-[missng module name]-5.6.9
For each of the above modules (in fact hash came with one of the others)

I also ran pkg install OpenSSL but I'm not sure if I needed to go that or not.

Comment: It also added recommendations to install intl module and an accelerator. but I haven't figured out that yet and when running composer install many other modules (following the same naming patterns) were also required